# Raid 6 on btrfs in Vivid

Tags: 15.04, raid, btrfs

Hi I'm trying to make a Raid 6 on multiple drives in Ubuntu 15.04, Btrfs is already running on 4 in raid10 when I do

```
sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid6 -mconvert=raid6 /mnt/storage/
```

it converts to raid6 with the message.

```
Done, had to relocate 3 out of 3 chunks
```

so that looks fine but when I with `df -h` the filesize seems wrong.
I'm using 4x 2TB drives and I was expecting the having 4TB space available like with Raid10, `df -h` is telling me I have 8TB available?

I'm running kernel 3.19.0-21-generic and Btrfs v3.17 which I get from `apt-get`.
Can anyone tell if did something wrong or does Raid6 on btrfs show the size differently?

BTW with raid10 I do see 4TB when I run `df -h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTRFS and `df` don't see eye-to-eye. Simply put BTRFS can hide things all over the place that need physical space but aren't directly available to the system like snapshots and metadata.

Take my RAID10 for example.

```
$ sudo btrfs filesystem show 
Label: ned  uuid: 567ea578-13a0-46c0-9a5c-513f028b7aac
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 187.05GiB
    devid    1 size 1.36TiB used 119.53GiB path /dev/sdg
    devid    2 size 1.36TiB used 119.53GiB path /dev/sdi
    devid    3 size 1.36TiB used 119.53GiB path /dev/sdj
    devid    4 size 1.36TiB used 119.53GiB path /dev/sdk
```

4×1.3TiB drives should render about 3TiB of raw space. With "187GiB" used, on a traditional filesystem, that should leave me with 2.8TiB free.

`df` sees the drives but doesn't understand how they work together:

```
$ df -h /media/ned/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdk        5.5T  375G  5.1T   7% /media/ned
```

Even my version of `btrfs-tools` (3.12) doesn't understand enough to tell me free space:

```
$ btrfs fi df /media/ned/
Data, RAID10: total=238.00GiB, used=186.62GiB
System, RAID10: total=64.00MiB, used=48.00KiB
Metadata, RAID10: total=1.00GiB, used=447.08MiB
unknown, single: total=160.00MiB, used=0.00
```

Apparently this gets a lot better with 3.18 and up but you'll need Wily (or a PPA or to compile it yourself) for that. I've just [compiled this for myself](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php?title=Btrfs_source_repositories) and it looks a lot healthier:

```
$ sudo ./btrfs fi usage /media/ned/
Overall:
    Device size:           5.46TiB
    Device allocated:        478.12GiB
    Device unallocated:        4.99TiB
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:            374.11GiB
    Free (estimated):          2.54TiB  (min: 2.54TiB)
    Data ratio:               2.00
    Metadata ratio:           2.00
    Global reserve:      160.00MiB  (used: 0.00B)
```

Anyway, you can read more about this on the [BTRFS Wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#How_much_free_space_do_I_have.3F).

Comment: Soo since `sudo btrfs filesystem df /mnt/storage/
Data, RAID6: total=2.00GiB, used=803.61MiB
System, RAID6: total=64.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, RAID6: total=1.00GiB, used=2.17MiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=16.00MiB, used=0.00B` show RAID6 I shouldn't look at df to see disk space.

Comment: Yup. `df` is currently near-useless on BTRFS. I've just added output from the new `btrfs fi usage` command which seems to be a lot better.